# C# 相対パスでファイル検索をしたい

Tags: c#

現在実行しているEXEファイルと検索対象フォルダであるNameは、同じ階層にあります。
そして、Nameフォルダ内にある、1つのファイル(ファイル名はランダム)を相対パスで取得したいのですが、取得することが出来ません。

現在のC#での実装は

```
var file = Directory.GetFiles("Name","*.DAT");
```

としており、var fileにはなにも入らない状態です。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

階層を特に限定しない場合、相対パスの解決には`System.Uri`を使用します。

```
var dirPath = new Uri(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "./Name").LocalPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

Exeのディレクトリを取得するということで良いんでしょうか

```
var file = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Name"), "*.DAT");
```

とか、

```
var file = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Name"), "*.DAT");
```